# How to install Ubuntu16 into a system with console as the only display

Tags: boot, command-line, system-installation, upgrade

I'm trying to install the Ubuntu16 into my embedded system. But my system only has serial console as the display output so ordinary methods seems not work. Is there a special image or a special tool for this case? Currently, I'm running a highly customized Ubuntu 14 in that system. Is that possible/hard to upgrade from that?

I also poked around and when it boots from usb key, I saw the following options. But when I try 'cli', it failed right away with 'No such file or directory'. Is it a deprecated option?

> Available boot methods:
>   install
>   Start the installation -- this is the default option.
>   expert
>   Start the installation in expert mode, for maximum control.
>   cli, cli-expert
>   Minimal command-line system install.
>   memtest
>   Perform a memory test.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "*my system only has console as the display output so ordinary methods seems not work*"? What does not work?

Comment: A net install using the Ubuntu mini.iso might work. It only uses an ncurses interface during installation.

Comment: @techraf: I think it will look up the monitor by default and stuck there

Comment: You wrote "*seems not work*" then asked what does it mean you replied "*I think*". I meant what is the reality, what do you have, what do you do, what error do you get, not what you think.

Comment: Here is what I got:
>  boot:                                                                           
>  Undefined video mode number: 314                                                
>  Press <ENTER> to see video modes available, <SPACE> to continue, or wait 30 sec

Comment: @AlcuinArundel Thanks! I will give it a try but from the document the only difference is mini.iso will download the packages instead...

Comment: That's a little misleading; there's no graphical installer with the mini.iso, but yes, you do need an internet connection to use it.

Comment: Before you try the mini.iso, there' s something else to try first: when you boot up the live usb and get to the menu, hit `f6`. A grey menu should appear. Select `nomodeset`. Then select "Try Ubuntu" and see what happens. If that doesn't work, try `acpi=off`.

Comment: Did it work? If so let me know and I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. mini.iso will hit the same problem (Press <ENTER> to see video modes available, <SPACE> to continue, or wait 30 sec). I'm feeling like it's actually booting now, but just no output in the console. There's no difference for acpi=off (I also tried with console=tty0,115200n8). And f6 is not working at all (it will just print a '~').